# Zoomed in by accident XBMC

Tags: kodi

I played around with the XBMC remote for iOS and I suddenly was zoomed in (or changed resolution) not just the aspect ratio where you fill the screen, it's off and too big.
I can't access the settings because it's off screen.

Is there a hotkey to unzoom or change resolution? I don't want to reset completely because I don't want to lose my other settings.

It's not Z, it must be resolution related

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding true to advancedsettings.xml